# How can I setup my react app in ubuntu server

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I completed few tasks in react js and I want to move them to server for my client review. But I don't know, how to ru this react app in server. Currently I am using http://localhost:3000

Here I have couple of questions.
1. Do we need to configure all the necessary settings in ubuntu server as well..?
2. I have a IP address pointed to my Ubuntu. So, how can I use that IP for running the app in server?

Here is my webpack.production.js file

```html
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
  entry: './main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist/assets'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/',
    sourceMapFilename: '[name].map'
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true,
      debug: false
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      beautify: false,
      mangle: {
        screw_ie8: true,
        keep_fnames: true
      },
      compress: {
        screw_ie8: true
      },
      comments: false
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

```html
"scripts": {
    "start": "if-env NODE_ENV=production && npm run start:prod || npm run start:dev",
    "start:dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline  --history-api-fallback",
    "start:prod": "webpack && node server.js",
    "build": "webpack -p --config ./webpack.production.config.js",
    "build:dev": "webpack --env=dev --progress --profile --colors",
    "build:dist": "webpack --env=production --progress --profile --colors"
  }
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Webpack to create the bundle you need to move the *index.html* and the *bundle.js* to your client's server and configure a HTTP server like Nginx or Apache to point to the *index.html* file.

Comment: I created few components and those are connected to PHP server through API call's.

So if we just copy index.html and bundle.js, then how can we get those components and other js related files..?

Comment: You can create different domains with Apache or Nginx you can mount your server into `http://youraddress/api` and your React application in `http://youraddress/`. You should look at this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) to get a grasp on how to configure them. (My server of choice is Nginx).

Comment: My questions was, how to setup my react project in production. I know, how to configure Apache and PHP. So, I can able to handle Web Services. But, When I try build the react script, then I didn't get any build folder(Even I didn't get any errors). So do I need to configure all software's like npm, react in my server..?

Even, if i configure them in server, then how can i access them. By default it will give localhost or local IP. But I need elastic IP.

Can you please suggest me on this..?

Comment: This is a very broad question. You should only need to copy index.html and the bundle.js from Webpack in the server. If you're not able to get those in your local machine you problably have a silent error or Webpack not correctly configured. If you're able to get them, then you just need to copy them to your configured Apache server.

Comment: I just updated my question with my webconfig.production file and package.json file. Can you please check it once. I followed the same way as mentioned above and generated bundle.js file. Now I copierd bundle.js, index.html along with few other dependent js and css files to my server. Now, I am getting this error - 
Warning: It looks like you're using a minified copy of the development build of React. When deploying React apps to production, make sure to use the production build which skips development warnings and is faster

Comment: You just need to follow the link they provide and do the indicated modifications in your webpack.conf to use the production build.

Comment: I am not getting any error or suggestion links, when we execute build command. Can you give me some reference links or is there any possible to check my web.config file for errors..?

Comment: Here you have the link. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html You need to do the point specific for Webpack. Anyways this is a warning. It shouldn't block the execution of the application. So my bet is that you have the problem somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. I am cross checking entire project. If I found any answer, then I will post it here.

Comment: Finally issue resolved. I configured Plunk and generated buidl file using the same. Now I can able to run the build file in server.
Here I pointed my server to the exact folder where the build files are there.

Thanks for your response.

Comment: I'm glad! You can accept one of the answers just to indicate that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

That question is very broad. In case you have a Server, you need to login there using ssh and install Apache or another Server like nginx. I guess your reacft app does not depend on PHP, or node, so it is static html with JS. So basically:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Will install the server and to check if it is running just use a browser and navigate to `http://<your server ip>` and you should see a page saying: »It's working«

If so:

```
cd /var/www/html
rm -rf *
exit

cd /your/local/project
scp -r * user@<your server ip>:/var/www/html
```

That should upload all your file to `/var/www/html`. If you then get a `Forbidden` response, you need to `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data *` in `/var/www/html`

Have a look here https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html

But, however, setting up a server becomes more complex, depending on your needs: like node/php/mysql support and of course the OS, the instructions above are suitable for ubuntu. Additionally no considerations about security are included, so be careful if do not know what you are doing!

Comment: I created few components and those are linked with API calls through a PHP server. So, is there any way to run my project in aws server. I done all installations. When I place host as my IP address, then it is saying
listen EADDRNOTAVIL <IP ADDRESS>:3030