# Run React basic app on ubuntu using node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ubuntu

I am fairly new to NodeJS, here is the problem statement:
I have a small app (let's consider default app) of ReactJS. I installed NodeJs on my Ubuntu Server. Now when I hit mydomain.com in a browser I want my ReactJS app to show there. I know I need to do some configuration but somehow not able to find what's the right way of doing it. I have nothing installed on my Ubuntu server except NodeJS and npm.

Any suggestion will help me.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I setup my react app in ubuntu server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43673366/how-can-i-setup-my-react-app-in-ubuntu-server)

Answer (score 0):

For pure `Node.js` solution, tou can use static files (HTML/JS/CSS) HTTP server like following

- https://github.com/cloudhead/node-static
- https://github.com/indexzero/http-server

I've used `http-server` which is super simple and can be installed as a CLI tool as well